# Multiple instance of Microsoft.XMLHTTP

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I try to connect a Website with multiple User Logins.

While connecting the site the Session-ID is set as a cookie in the Web-Browser. 
I tried to solve this by generating an Array of Object.

```
For i = 1 To Cnz
  Set oHttp(i) = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Next i
```

Unfortunatelly it looks like all XMLHTTP objects share the same Cookie Session ID.

Is there a way to have independent Browser Objects ? 
Or set the cookies manually  ? 
Or use a different Object to sent http, Get Result while managing Session-ID with cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `MakeSessionRequest` function you can retrieve the session id which is stored in cookie and pass it on to server on all subsequent request using

`xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "<key>=<value>"`

```
Function MakeSessionRequest(method As String, url As String, data As String, _
 ByRef cookie As String, Optional ByRef updateCookie = False) As Byte()

  If Len(cookie) = 0 Then cookie = "dummy=dummy;"
  httpReferrer = Trim(url)
  postVars = Trim(data)

  Dim XMLHTTP As Object

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHttp")
    XMLHTTP.Open method, Trim(url), False

    If UCase(method) = "POST" Then
      XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", _
                       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    End If
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Referer", httpReferrer 'in case the server cares
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "to deal with XMLHTTP bug"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
    XMLHTTP.send postVars

    'wait for response
    While XMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
      XMLHTTP.waitForResponse 1000
    Wend

    ' extract the cookie data from the response header
    If updateCookie Then
      cookie = ""
      strHeaders = XMLHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders()
      hArr = Split(strHeaders, "Set-Cookie: ")
      For kk = 1 To UBound(hArr)
          theCookie = Left(hArr(kk), InStr(hArr(kk), "path=/") - 2)
          cookie = cookie & " " & theCookie
      Next
    End If

    'return the response body
    MakeSessionRequest = XMLHTTP.responseBody
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```